# Живые обои

Tags: java

Как сделать живые обои с покадровая анимацией? Можно ли использовать ImageView и как это реализовать? Если нельзя, то подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать?

Comment: Под какую платформу делать "живые обои" собираетесь? Какое устройство? Для ПК (Windows)? Для Андроид? Другая ОС?

Comment: для андройд, делаю в eclipse, использую avd 3.2" HVGA slider